# Why do I have to use whole new line to print the variables separately?

Tags: java

```
public class whloop_practice_01 {
  public static void main(String[]args) {
    int cookies_eaten = 0;
    int cookies_left_in_jar = 20;

    while(cookies_left_in_jar > 0) {
      System.out.println("I ate cookie number ");
      System.out.println(cookies_eaten);
      cookies_eaten++;
      System.out.println(cookies_left_in_jar);
      System.out.println("Cookies left in the jar");
      cookies_left_in_jar--;
    }
  }
}
```

Newbie here

The above code works perfectly. However, if I try to write 
`System.out.println("I ate cookie number", cookies_eaten)` 
the IDE marks this line as error. But I did the similar thing in Python and it worked perfectly. Why do I actually have to print the variable in a whole new line writing `System.out.println(cookies_eaten)`?

Comment: What it has to do with python?

Comment: Java uses a plus sign, not a comma. `System.out.println("I ate cookie number" + cookies_eaten)`

Comment: Because Java isn't Python.  Language designers all make their own decisions about how to do things, so questions like "Why can I do blah-blah-blah in language X but not in language Y" really don't make any more sense than asking "How come I have dark hair and the person next to me is blonde?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either do

```
System.out.println("I ate cookie number " + cookies_eaten  + .....);
```

or

```
System.out.print("I ate cookie number");
System.out.print(cookies_eaten);
.....
```

NOTE:  "....." denotes your additional code

println creates a new line each time (I believe it creates a new line before printing), while print keeps it on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
System.out.println("I ate cookie number" + cookies_eaten);
```

You can concatenate strings using `+` in Java.

If you like to use print command like **C**, use `printf`.
eg.

```
printf("I ate cookie number %d", cookies_eaten);
```

Answer (score 0):

Different programming languages have different ways of doing things. You cant do certain things in same way in every programming language.

There are methods give an output like,

```
System.out.print();
System.out.println();
System.out.printf();
```

Use them according to your needs,

In this case you can use all above methods as follows.

1. `System.out.print("I ate cookie number"); System.out.print(cookies_eaten);`
2. `System.out.println("I ate cookie number"+cookies_eaten);`
3. `System.out.printf("I ate cookie number %d", cookies_eaten);`